# Timezone change in RHEL4.9

Tags: redhat, timezone, rhel4

I wanted to change timezone in my rhel4.9 box from IST to GMT. What steps do i have to follow. And will this require a restart in applications or reboot of the server??

Comment: Hi Yoonix... I just want to know whether changing the timezone requires applications restart or server reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Timezone configuration is located in `/etc/sysconfig/clock`

```
ZONE="GMT"
```

I don't think there is any need of restarting anything.

Comment: Figured out the answer... We do have to restart applications if there is any dependency. Also system daemons such as ntp and syslog has to be restarted to catch up the time.